# how to use a recipe from a different chef cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

For some development work, there is a requirement to temporarily include a recipe (lets say, myapp::recipe1) into a single node from a stack. I don't want to modify the original project itself for a temp solution on a single node. Any feedback on the below approach that i am planning on?

1. Add the cookbook (myapp) into the Berksfile of the original cookbook, like so:
    cookbook 'myapp', git:  'git@github.com:/ABC/myapp.git'
2. Do a berks, so that it uploads the cookbook 'myapp' into the Organization of the chef-server
3. Add the recipe "myapp::recipe1" via the Chef management console on the particular node
4. trigger a manual chef-client on the node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the described use case, I would do the exact same.